# How to create model quickly&elegantly with Linq To Sql in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

Ok straight to the issue. I can get object mapping to tables easily with Linq To Sql. For instance: class **Product**, class **Order**, class **Order_Detail** from Northwind. IMO, these 3 object have already met model's meet. But i can't put some useful attr(**[Required] [HttpPost]**) on properties of them(except modifying **design.cs**, which is not recommended).Do i have to create **ProductModels OrderModels** with the same properties myself, and maybe some additional DAL-like classes to turn the linq2sql objects to models??

EDIT:
Even if i put design.cs and my models in the same namespace, how can i make two partial classes have the same properties??

Comment: [The generated classes are partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: @bzlm How to make two partial classes have the same properties??

Comment: sounds like you need [buddy classes](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/01/28/separating-metadata-classes-from-model-classes-in-dataannotations-using-custom.aspx)!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should create DTO's for each Linq to SQL model, it is not considered a good practice to pass Linq2Sql objects through your layers.

Optionally, look into to using Entity Framework Code First. It is stupid simple to use and you can add validation attributes directly to your POCOs, which are enforced on the data persistence side as well as the presentation side in MVC.

here's a good EF codefirst primer : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx